# PHP: why is interface method declared abstract?

Tags: php

According to http://php.net/manual/en/class.outeriterator.php, interface OuterIterator is declared like this:

```
 OuterIterator extends Iterator {
    /* Methods */
    public Iterator getInnerIterator ( void )

    /* Inherited methods */
    abstract public mixed Iterator::current ( void )
    abstract public scalar Iterator::key ( void )
    abstract public void Iterator::next ( void )
    abstract public void Iterator::rewind ( void )
    abstract public boolean Iterator::valid ( void )
}
```

In PHP, interface methods can't contain implementation. So why are these methods, in OuterIterator interface, declared abstract? And why is getInnerIterator not declared abstract?

Comment: It is just to make clear what YOU have to implement if you use this interface. This is actually not valid PHP.

Comment: Over at the docs, click the link on `Iterator`: `getInnerIterator()` is not a method found in `Iterator` but a new one added to this implementation